# How to make an account validation program with many accounts?

Tags: java, database, validation

Can someone give me an example?
If there are many accounts, how will the program understand from which login is the right password? Can I save account to file somehow like this:

```
login:password
```

Comment: Do you want to save logins and passwords in DataBase?

Comment: You must use an ID sequence to 'bind' the account to login, these ID must be the same on login, in order you identify each account to each right login and password.

Comment: No matter how you implement it, if this ever goes into production, you should absolutely never store the passwords in plain text. Always generate a hash of them before you save them to disk / database / whatsoever!

Comment: B_Osipiuk, yes.
How about JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

Login

```
id_login (unique sequence)
id_account
login
password
```

Account:

```
id_account
account_name
```

This way, you must fill the same value for id_account in both objects. Hope is usefull.